# Is there a way to add static function to Object in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

There is a way to add functions and properties to via 'prototype' property of every class. However those new functions will only be available in this class instances. Question: Is it possible to add static functions and properties to Object in runtime?

Comment: did you try using "dynamic classes" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible. Static methods are part of a class definition and need to exist at compile-time. If you need to add functions at runtime that are statically callable, you can do so easily enough with an approach like this:

```
public class StaticMethods
{
    private static var _map:Object = {};

    public static function add(name:String, method:Function):void
    {
        _map[name] = method;
    }

    public static function call(name:String, ...args):*
    {
        if(_map[name])
        {
            return _map[name].apply(StaticMethods, args);
        }
    }
}
```

With its usage being like so:

```
function sum(a:int, b:int):int
{
    return a + b;
}


StaticMethods.add("sum", sum);

trace(StaticMethods.call("sum", 5, 10)); // 15
```

I wouldn't advise this capability though; it will lead to code that is *very* difficult to debug and maintain.

Comment: Yeah, you can achieve this by `Singleton Pattern`. Although I think static vars or function may fit for `utils`.